# Can't complete `auto` variable of C++11 in Code::Blocks

Tags: c++, c++11, codeblocks

This problem is very easy to encounter, but very hard to describe.
I use Code::Blocks 13.12, test the code snippet as follows:

```
auto xxx = std::string("test");
xxx.
```

When the trailing `.` is entered, there should be a context menu of auto completion popup, but it doesn't.

But if I give the right type of `xxx` like that:

```
std::string xxx = std::string("test");
xxx.
```

The complete menu pops up as normal. Does the completion feature not support C++11 yet? Or it just can't complete the `auto` type?

Comment: The C++ standard doesn't mandate IDE features :)

Comment: Get a better IDE / auto completer? Parsing C++ is hard, apparently Code::Blocks is not perfect.

Comment: Finally something VS does better! :)

Comment: The codeblocks code insight seems to be fairly crap and it breaks on a just about anything that wasn't C++03.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the C++ standard.

Comment: Not sure why everyone is going on about the standard, OP was clearly asking about the behaviour of a particular IDE

Comment: Because it wasn't asked in proper English, it's easy to misinterpret the question _"Is the completed feature not support C++11 still?"_ and assume it's asking about something provided by C++11.

Comment: @M.M And his particular IDE obviously does not have that feature. /Thread

Answer (score -1):

Go to Settings -> Compiler and find a C++ compiler with compiler flag -std=c++11, choose the flag and save.

Comment: That option is mean the compilation standards, not completion setup.